# Facebook login callback session always closed

Tags: android, facebook, session, facebook-graph-api

I have a facebook login feature in my app. Now my code works well in the emulator. But when I tried testing it to a android phone. There's no error but the session appears to be always closed even if I'm logged in.

Here's my code:

```
Session session = Session.getActiveSession();
    //check if user is logged in at facebook

    if (session != null && session.isOpened()) {
        Log.i("", "Session Open");
        Request.executeMeRequestAsync(session, new Request.GraphUserCallback() {

            // callback after Graph API response with user object
            @Override
            public void onCompleted(GraphUser user, Response response) {
              if (user != null) {
                  facebookId = user.getId();
                  loginType = 2;
                  LogMeIn();

              }
            }
          });
    } 
    else    
    {
        Log.i("", "Session Closed");
        // start Facebook Login
        Session.openActiveSession(this, true, new Session.StatusCallback() {

          // callback when session changes state
          @Override
          public void call(Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception) {
            if (session.isOpened()) {
                Log.i("", "Session Open");
              // make request to the /me API
              Request.executeMeRequestAsync(session, new Request.GraphUserCallback() {

                // callback after Graph API response with user object
                @Override
                public void onCompleted(GraphUser user, Response response) {
                  Log.i("", "Complete");
                  if (user != null) {
                      facebookId = user.getId();
                      loginType = 2;
                      LogMeIn();

                  }
                }
              });
            }
            else
            {
                Log.i("", "Session Closed"); //I always end up here
            }
          }
        });
    }
```

As you can see. I always end up on the session closed part when checking for the session after the session changed. I don't know what's wrong but this seemed to work on the emulator. Now, the code for getting the information of the graph user is not happening. Any ideas? Thanks!

Additional information: I tried to logged out my fb account. And hit my login button on my app. It redirects me to the login screen of the facebook, but again, the code for getting the graph user did not happen because the session is closed.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using session in fragment, try this code, it works for me:

```
else {
    Log.d("ss", "Session Closed");
    // start Facebook Login
    Session.openActiveSession(getActivity(),
    MyFragment.this, true, callback);
}
```

Don't forget to use `UiLifecycleHelper` for `onActivityResult`, `onResume`, `onCreate`, `onDestroy`, `onSaveInstancceState`... 
or manage the session yourself to save the state.